# O que esse código significa/faz?

Tags: javascript, html, array, dom

Bom, estou aprendendo a usar JavaScript, principalmente a trabalhar com *index*, e sempre me deparo com isso, mas quero entender direito o que cada parte significa, pois não quero usar sem realmente entender...

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  txt = txt + x.options[i].text + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Eu fechei por 2 motivos. Primeiro, que aparentemente tem um erro no código (length do x e não do options). Precisaria de um [mcve] para validar. Segundo que se não deixar clara a parte que entendeu, dá pra ficar o dia todo fazendo perguntas similares cada vez que muda um pequeno detalhe sem que seja útil pra qualquer outra pessoa na busca. . Estudar a postagem disponível neste link pode fazer uma diferença muito positiva no seu entendimento e aproveitamento do site para as próximas: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Comment: bom, obrigado pela explicação, eu acho...

Comment: Só pra adiantar o assunto, a finalidade do site é (ao menos era, originalmente) criar um repositório de conhecimento que sirva para futuros visitantes com problemas do mesmo tipo. A sua, como não tem um problema de fato, só serve para seu caso específico, o que cai mais no modelo helpdesk/ajuda individual. Mas isso tudo está bem melhor explicado no link, além de várias outras coisas extremamente relevantes. O fato de ter erro acaba piorando a situação, pois se trata de um pedido de explicação de funcionamento de algo que não funciona;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Minha sugestão é aprender a programar passo por passo, entender cada mecanismo da linguagem, ir estruturadamente formando seu conhecimento. Nunca vi alguém (deve existir em algum lugar) que conseguiu aprender bem só lendo códigos dos outros. Como complemento pode ser útil.

Este código nem é muito bom, a não ser que tenha um contexto maior, mesmo assim é improvável. E justamente por não ter um contexto dá pra falar só sobre o mecanismo e não a intenção geral.

Variáveis deveriam ter seu escopo limitado ao menor trecho possível, neste caso é o próprio `for`, então por que a declaração da variável está fora? A não ser que tenha algum motivo parece que a pessoa que escreveu não sabe bem o que está fazendo. Embora o `var` não ajuda muito, e pro escopo ficar realmente restrito deveria usar o `let` (o que dá alguma polêmica porque alguns navegadores não o aceitam, mas eu tenho a impressão que isto é tão pouco e gera tanta dificuldade que pra navegadores antigos deveria ter outra versão do código de qualquer jeito, ou ainda poderia fazer uma tradução posterior com [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Esse laço é bem padrão e percorre todo um *array*, ele vai da posição 0 desse *array* até o número anterior ao seu tamanho (se começa do 0 a última posição é o tamanho -1, o que dá certo porque foi usado o operador `<`(menor que), então quando for igual ele já não executa mais). Ele vai adicionando um no índice em cada passo, o tal do `i++`, isto é o mesmo que `i = i + 1` que é pegar o valor de `i`, somar 1 e guardar o novo valor em `i` mesmo.

Dentro a execução é ir concatenando uma *string* em cada passo. Não tem o código mas ele deve começar com um texto vazio ou um cabeçalho único. A parte da direita da expressão é o que faz essa concatenação, ele pega o valor já existente e soma com o resto a seguir, e guarda tudo na própria variável que tem então um novo valor que será usado no próximo passo. Poderia ser escrito assim:

```
txt += x.options[i].text + "<br>";
```

O que está sendo concatenado são duas partes, uma expressão com uma variável e o literal que é uma *tag* HTML que quebra a linha.

A parte da variável está bem esquisita e provavelmente errada, mas novamente, sem contexto não posso garantir.

Quando percorre o objeto `x` espera-se que ele seja um *array*. E vai andando nos elementos dele, algo assim:

```
x[i]
```

Porém não é o que está sendo feito. Como o índice está sendo usado em `options` este é o *array* e é ele que deve varrer, portanto é um erro pegar o tamanho de `x`, deveria pegar o tamanho de `x.options` que é um objeto dentro do outro.

Por fim dentro desse *array* `options` tem algum objeto, que não sabemos qual é, mas ao que tudo indica um dos membros dele (uma propriedade que ele tem) é `text` e é isto que está pegando.

Assim este código deveria ser algo assim:

```
let txt = "";
for (let i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
    txt += x.options[i].text + "<br>";
}
```

Note que por `options` ser um *array* tem uma propriedade chamada `length`. Se isto não está dando erro então `x` também tem, mas não está varrendo o mesmo objeto. Pode estar até funcionando por coincidência, mas acho que nem roda.

Se quiser pode eliminar as chaves já que é só uma linha:

```
let txt = "";
for (let i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) txt += x.options[i].text + "<br>";
```

A variável `txt` vai fora do laço mesmo porque ela provavelmente será usada fora, se não então não faz sentido ter isso.

Lembrando que só use o `let` se tiver certeza que não rodará em navegadores recentes ou se fará alguma tradução para rodar nos antigos.

Não entendeu tudo? Provavelmente porque está faltando o fundamento de cada coisa, por isso que precisa ir construindo o conhecimento de forma estruturada, um tijolo de cada vez, e começando pelo alicerce, ir subindo a parade, fazendo o teto, o acabamento, etc. Se não souber explicar por conta própria cada mecanismo individual não pode passar para a próxima.

Tentando fazer um exemplo funcional que eu acho que era a intenção dese código que parece todo errado:

```js
let x = document.getElementById("exemplo");
let txt = "";
for (let i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) txt += x.options[i].text + "<br>";
console.log(txt);
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="exemplo" size="4">
    <option>Facebook</option>
    <option>Twitter</option>
    <option>Linkedin</option>
    <option>Instagram</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/GetOptions.js).

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação. Bom, pra aprender melhor eu costumo praticar desenvolvendo alguns códigos que vêm à cabeça, mas só quando eu acho que já tenho o conhecimento necessário, mas vez ou outra me deparo com uma situação dessas, de coisas as quais não entendo a estrutura completa...enfim, foi uma resposta bem completa, vai ajudar bastante...

Comment: É porque desestruturou seu aprendizado. Note que está tentando aprender por um exemplo errado e por não entendê-lo não pode detectar isso, imagina quanta coisa não dá erro, você não aprendeu o fundamento daquilo e aprende algo errado desta forma.

Comment: Sim, é um código de um terceiro, mas não levei pro meu código, só queria entender direito como que a estrutura trabalhava pra dar o valor pra essa variável i que ele cria... Ah! E o elemento que ele tá usando como array é uma tag <select>, e cada index dela é uma <option>...